# I want to change the launcher of my program that will start with a login screen and then upon login it goes to a tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LogMainActivity"> <!--TabbedMainActivity-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ReminderService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".TabbedMainActivity"
            /><!--LogMainActivity-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Television" />

        <!--<activity android:name=".MyTextView">-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have already changed the manifest.xml to logmainactivity as the launcher despite the changes, my program stopped working upon lauching.It is not displaying the login screen.

Here is the log for the beginning of the crash
 --------- beginning of crash------------------------
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification, PID: 2237
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification/com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification.LogMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification.LogMainActivity.onCreate(LogMainActivity.java:20)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

---Here is my login main activity ---

```
package com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;


public class LogMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     MyTextView User;
     MyTextView signin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        User = (MyTextView)findViewById(R.id.user);
        signin = (MyTextView)findViewById(R.id.admin);

        User.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LogMainActivity.this,TabbedMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });

        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LogMainActivity.this,TabbedMainActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);


            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Would you share your error log while crash the app

Comment: Please Share Your crash logcat report

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference at com.example.mypc.tabbed_notification.LogMainActivity.onCreate(LogMainActivity.java:20)`

Comment: You are calling `setOnClickListener()` on a null object refrerence.

Comment: please share `activity_main` code as well.